# Does blender only let you add physics to one model? - mmdtools

Tags: physics, eevee-render-engine, baking, mmd-tools

I've been trying to work on mmd animations for some time and I've noticed something. The first time I used the built in physics tool in the mmdtools add-on was when I only had one model, one stage, nothing else. Nothing really complex. The next time I tried to use it was when I was doing a more complex one that was extremely hard to do with my horrible gpu and lag every time I clicked something. It had about 17 models and who knows how many stages, not that it really matters. I tried adding physics to all of them since you can only do it once (I think? I kinda came to that conclusion too, it doesn't let me bake a 2nd time after I've done it once unless I delete the bake) and literally all of them didn't work even though I was on frame 1 when I added the physics AND baked them and I was so confused so I just removed the physics. It was really hard to tell if it worked or not cause again, my laggy laptop but I think only 3 made it. I'm not completely sure, the only one I'm sure did make was a pink one the others I saw no progress but after struggling with rendering issues (if you saw my other questions) I ended up getting frustrated and scraped it. Finally, I started a new one and I added physics a bit earlier this time, and only for 1 of them it worked, the other's failed. I can't even check my theory either cause all the blender mmd tests I see are only with one model, which is what I did the first time. So, am I right or wrong and is there a way to fix this or am I just doing something wrong? I stay on frame 1 and add the physics to the armature, not the model (made that mistake the first time) and then bake all physics and it still manages to fail? I could just use wiggle bone and cloth simulation but it's gonna be really hard to do wiggle bone, it's manageable but I'm a very impatient person and I still don't understand cloth simulation which is nice. :)

Hey, it's me from the future. I just saw a comment about the mmd model's size for the physics to work. They said it needed to be 0.1 but I make mine 0.2. Is that the reason why it's not working? I feel like I've done 0.2 before and it worked cause I was following a tutorial but I can't check cause I deleted the project lol..

I'm back, I tried resizing it to 0.1 instead of 0.2 and it's still not working, even after I baked it. Either Blender doesn't like me and doesn't want to work or I'm seriously doing something wrong.

Yup, it only works for one person. I've been trying it for a few hours with only one model and it's working well, and then I just tried with 2 people and it broke..again.

Comment: What is mmd physics? Usually, you should put a physics simulation on all involved objects before baking anything.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I do, I add physics to all of my models first and then press bake all physics and it still doesn't work. Also, when I say mmd physics I mean the built-in physics with the mmd-tool addon, which adds the physics from the actual mmd model onto your model but fit into Blender's standards.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Also, if it helps, I was using the first part of these tutorials (before it went into the cloth physics) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4y6tOjvLC8&t=52s. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xfyh5xY_kc&t=79s